How to find coordinates of points on the circle, which is formed from intersection of two spheres?
What i did:
I can find the center of a circle (x, y, z) and its radius, but how to calculate certain coordinates (let it be 10 or 20 points) on the circle? I think each step for forming points on the circle contains cos(a). For example (case of 20 points): first point depend on the cos(18), second is depend on the cos(36), 20'th point is depend on the cos(360).
Image is made by @DMGregory: https://i.sstatic.net/iECiuPj8.png
To this picture are only added interested of me coordinates (blue dots on green circle).
Example:
There are two spheres:
s1: (x0 - 1.0)^2 + (y0 - 1.5)^2 + (z0 - 1.5)^2 = 4
s2: (x0 - 3.0)^2 + (y0 - 3.0)^2 + (z0 - 1.0)^2 = 6
Could someone find 2 or 3 points on the circle (intersection of spheres), which are separated by constant length between each other?
P.S.: I want to implement this algorithm in a program that works with a data set of billions of coordinates of the centers of the spheres (they definitely intersect). Thus, whenever possible, the most economical (in terms of time and speed) sequence of actions is preferable.
Here is the code to calculate the center of a circle formed by the intersection of two spheres with constant radii.
def water_function_group_distance(x0=None, y0=None, z0=None,
                                  x1=None, y1=None, z1=None):
    """Find distance"""
    x, z = sympy.symbols('x z', real=True)
    eq0 = sympy.Eq((x - x0) ** 2 + (z - z0) ** 2, 2.7 ** 2)
    eq1 = sympy.Eq((x - x1) ** 2 + (z - z1) ** 2, 2.7 ** 2)
    answer0 = sympy.solve([eq0, eq1])
    if answer0:
        x_coords = []
        y_coords = []
        z_coords = []
        x, y = sympy.symbols('x y', real=True)
        eq2 = sympy.Eq((x - x0) ** 2 + (y - y0) ** 2, 2.7 ** 2)
        eq3 = sympy.Eq((x - x1) ** 2 + (y - y1) ** 2, 2.7 ** 2)
        answer1 = sympy.solve([eq2, eq3])
        if answer1:
            y, z = sympy.symbols('y z', real=True)
            eq4 = sympy.Eq((y - y0) ** 2 + (z - z0) ** 2, 2.7 ** 2)
            eq5 = sympy.Eq((y - y1) ** 2 + (z - z1) ** 2, 2.7 ** 2)
            answer2 = sympy.solve([eq4, eq5])
            if answer2:
                for q in answer0:
                    for k, v in q.items():
                        if k == z:
                            z_coords.append(v)
                        if k == x:
                            x_coords.append(v)
                for q in answer1:
                    for k, v in q.items():
                        if k == x:
                            x_coords.append(v)
                        if k == y:
                            y_coords.append(v)
                for q in answer2:
                    for k, v in q.items():
                        if k == y:
                            y_coords.append(v)
                        if k == z:
                            z_coords.append(v)
                if len(x_coords) != 0 and len(y_coords) != 0 and len(y_coords) != 0:
                    x_average = math.fsum(x_coords) / len(x_coords)
                    y_average = math.fsum(y_coords) / len(y_coords)
                    z_average = math.fsum(z_coords) / len(z_coords)
                    r_point = [x_average, y_average, z_average]
                    return r_point```
> Is this code OK?
   [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/iECiuPj8.png


HINT:
Subtraction of one sphere equation from the equation of the other
$$s1-s2=0 $$
is a plane ( not a circle ). This is because $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ terms with unity coefficient cancel out and there are no $(xy,yz,zx)$ terms. The planes are arbitrary.
Then you can choose what circles or other lines are required on the plane of intersection.

By subtraction do i get a plane which contains interesting of myself coordinates? Then should i substract plane and sphere? Is there a way only use only two coordinates? Thanks for advice, i'm not mathematician - so its difficult understand what here's going on (in the math exchange).

A plane and sphere intersect in a circle, yes.
